# Linked list insertion behaviour

Tags: c, linked-list

I found some odd behaviour in my C code last night.
I have a few base functions for creating and manipulating C Linked Lists.
The behaviour of my insert at nth position is odd though.

The first version works fine, but the second version does not insert at all into the list. Am I missing something?

```
//This works fine
void insert_nth(struct node** head, int data, int n_pos){
    if (n_pos == 0){
        insert_top(head, data);
        return;
    }
    struct node* current = *head;
    for(int i = 0; i < n_pos - 1 ; i++){
        if(current == NULL) return;
        else current = current->next;
    }
    if(current == NULL) return;
    insert_top(&(current->next), data);
}

//This doesn't insert at all
void insert_nth(struct node** head, int data, int n_pos){
    if (n_pos == 0){
        insert_top(head, data);
        return;
    }
    struct node* current = *head;
    for(int i = 0; i < n_pos ; i++){
        if(current == NULL) return;
        else current = current->next;
    }
    if(current == NULL) return;
    insert_top(&(current), data);
}
```

Here are the rest of the functions I'm using for reference.

```
int main(){
    struct node* head = NULL;
    build_rand_list(&head);
    list_print(&head);
    return 0;
}

void list_print(struct node** head){
    printf("List size is %d: List: ", list_length(head));
    for(struct node* current = *head; current!= NULL; current = current->next)
        printf("%d ", current->data);
    printf("\n");
}

void build_rand_list(struct node** head){
    //Assume head is NULL
    assert(*head == NULL);
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        int random_num = rand() % 11;
        insert_end(head, random_num);
    }
}

void insert_top(struct node** head, int data){
    struct node *new_node = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = *head;
    *head = new_node;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&(current)` is the address of a local variable.
`&(current->next)` is the address of a pointer inside a node in the list.

Modifying the local variable `current`, which is what `insert_top` ultimately does, has no effect on the list's nodes.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For example if you pass the node with the value 2 to the `insert_top` function the result will be something like this

[image: Linked list pointers]

It seems like you don't handle the pointers correctly. For example there is no node that points to the new node you created.

A better implementation would be

```
void insert_nth(struct node *head, int data, int npos) {
    struct node *current = head;

    for (int i = 0; i < npos - 1; i++) {
        current = current->next;

        if (current == null) {
            printf("%s\n", "Insert failed");
            return;
        }
    }

    struct node *new_node = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node *));
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = current->next;
    current->next = new_node;

    return;
}
```

Where the `head` parameter is the actual head of the list. 
The result will then me more satisfying. Hope this helps.

[image: Correct linked list pointers]